# Is it possible to extract from a map JSON file a list of a city's neighborhoods in a tree-structure format?

Tags: json

Forgive my ignorance, I am not experienced with JSON files. I've been trying to get a tree structure list of all the neighborhoods and locations in the city of Cape Town and this seems to be my last resort.

Unfortunately, I can't even open the file that can be found on this website - http://odp.capetown.gov.za/datasets/official-suburbs?geometry=18.107%2C-34.187%2C19.034%2C-33.988

Could someone tell me if it's possible to extract such as list.

I'd be forever thankful if someone could help me. Thank you in advance

Comment: have you downloaded the data in JSON format? The URL seems to be [this one](https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/8ebcd15badfe40a4ab759682aacf8439_75.geojson). What do you mean by "cannot open the file"? via editor? Are you using a language? maybe `jq`?

Comment: Once you have the file, this gives you a list of suburbs: `$ jq '.features | .[] | .properties.OFC_SBRB_NAME' ./Official_Suburbs.geojson`

Answer (score 1):

[I am making my comments an answer since I see no other suggestions and no information provided]

I am on a unix/linux shell but the following tools can also be found for windows. My solution for getting a quick list would be:

```
curl https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/8ebcd15badfe40a4ab759682aacf8439_75.geojson |\
     jq '.features | .[] | .properties.OFC_SBRB_NAME'
```

Which gives you:

```
"HYDE PARK"
"SPRINGFIELD"
"NIEUW MAASTRECHT-2"
"CHARLESVILLE"
"WILDWOOD"
"MALIBU VILLAGE"
"TUSCANY GLEN"
"VICTORIA MXENGE"
"KHAYELITSHA"
"CASTLE ROCK"
"MANSFIELD INDUSTRIA"
...
```

Explanation:

- `curl https://...` - curl downloads the JSON file from the API you are using
- `jq`: can process JSON on terminal and extract information. I do this in three steps:

  - `.features`: GeoJSON format seems to have a standard schema. All the retuned entries are in features *array*
  - `.[]` returns all elements in the array [docs here](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.3/)
  - `.properties.OFC_SBRB_NAME`: Each element of the array has a field called "properties" which from my understanding carries/includes metadata of this entry. One of those properties in `OFC_SBRB_NAME` which looks like a name and is the only string in each element. Thus I extract this.

Hope it helps. If you add more detail as to which platform you are using or language, etc I can update the answer, however, the methodology should remain the same I think